# Vue js how to prevent button clicked on two times continuously

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-directives

I have a button, user can click the button more than one time if he want. But when the user click the button, he might accidentally click twice, in such cases second click should be blocked by the code.

If I further explain. They should be a small delay between two clicks.

How do I achieve this using vue js?

In Vue docs [Event modifiers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers)
I found `.stop`

```
<button @click.stop="myFunction">Increase</button>
```

Does this do the job what I want?

Comment: No click.stop will just stop your event from propagating to parent elements.

Comment: you can add `disabled` attribute to the button once the button is clicked.
then remove the `disabled` attribute once the logic is done.

Comment: How about disabling the button for some time until the myFunction is executed using setTimeout?Here is the fiddle to check https://jsfiddle.net/vitragparekh/9k76oh23/6/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the `.stop` modifier does not solve your problem. What that modifier does is to prevent event propagation (it is equivalent to [stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) in plan JavaScript)

You could use the `.once` modifier to prevent any further events after the first one. However, if you want to allow multiple clicks, but have a delay between them, you could do something like this:

```
<template>
    <button :disabled="disabled" @click="delay">Increase</button>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        disabled: false,
        timeout: null
      }
    },
    methods: {
      delay () {
        this.disabled = true

        // Re-enable after 5 seconds
        this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
          this.disabled = false
        }, 5000)

        this.myFunction()
      },
      myFunction () {
        // Your function
      }
    },
    beforeDestroy () {
     // clear the timeout before the component is destroyed
     clearTimeout(this.timeout)
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

As others have said the `.stop` modifier will only stop the event from propagating up the DOM. To achieve the result you're looking for you could look into Lodash's [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#debounce) method ..

```
_.debounce(func, [wait=0], [options={}])
```

> Creates a debounced function that delays invoking `func` until after wait milliseconds have elapsed since the last time the debounced function was invoked.

Here's a simple example ..

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    counter: 0
  },
  methods: {
    myFunction() {
      this.counter++
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.debouncedMyFunction = debounce(this.myFunction, 300, {
      leading: true,
      trailing: false
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash.debounce@4.0.8/index.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click.stop="debouncedMyFunction">Increase</button>
  <p>
    {{ counter }}
  </p>
</div>
```

Specifying the `leading` option to true and `trailing` to false will cause the function to be invoked on the leading edge of the timeout instead of the trailing end. You can change the timeout value from 300 to your desired value in milliseconds.